# filter over an map object in python

Tags: python, list, parallel-processing, iterator, maps

I have been trying to use a map object instead of a list in order to calculate what I want because of spead issues. I use the following function:

```
def equ(vector):
    if (len(set(data[vector[0]]))==len(data[[vector[0],vector[1]]].drop_duplicates()[vector[0]]) and len(set(data[vector[0]]))==len(set(data[vector[1]]))):
        return vector
```

The vectors are pairs of columnnames and the function just returns the pair tuple if they are equivalent (this equivalence relation is something like= if two columns are equivalent then there exists a translation/dictionary between values from one to the other column).

Then I use the map:

```
value=spool.map(equ, list(itertools.combinations(subset,2)))
```

where subset is a subset of all my columnnames in data. When I get back the map object I tried to put it into a list and filter by taking all non None  elements. But this is extremely slow. Is there any way to filter first by all non empty elements over the map and then take the list (its unisual that they will be equivalent so that it would be a much shorter list)? I tried to apply the filter function over the map object, but that did not work.

I am using python3.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Pyhon3?

Comment: I am using python3.